# Parsing plain text from webpage

Tags: android, parsing

It's the very first time for me asking question on this forum, so hope that everyone won't be too strict.
  This semester I've been doing Project and I ***decided to make android application that will be able to parse articles from websites(not one, but many) and save it in text file or SQLite Database***. I've been doing this for already 5 months and I really don't know how can I get particular plain text from webpage without getting unrelated to particular article stuff, such as adds etc. 
Through this forum I found out how I can parse data from one website using Jsoup(I'm using one in my Project). And I thought it might work with multiple websites as well, but ***since many websites using different html tags to represent content of certain article, I couldn't find any common parameters that can be used***.
 I'm not sure, but I think I saw somebody on this forum said this kind of thing is impossible, but then how we can explain existence of such kind of apps like ***Pocket(Former Read it Later), Instapaper*** etc. These apps are doing what ultimately I want my app to do.
 So can anybody give any suggestions about what can I do about it? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Once you decide on which course to try first, come back with specific questions. Show us what you've tried, and where specifically you're getting stuck.  Or if you're having problems with code now, show your code, and then we are in a position to help.  Open-ended questions are usually closed quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it's going to show whole story, but here is the code:

doc = Jsoup.connect("http://"+URLField.getText().toString()+"").get();

```
                // get page title
                title = doc.title();
                doc = new Cleaner(Whitelist.none()).clean(doc);
```

Here I'm simply using Jsoup library and its Cleaner class, but I get a lot of text that I don't want to appear. I wanted to post image to make it clear(what I want), but this forum doesn't let me do that.